# intersection of two sets equals an LCM set

Tags: group-theory

I'm interested in how to prove the following:

> For every $n\in \Bbb N$, let $B_n = \{n·k| k\in \Bbb N\}$  where
>   $\Bbb N$ is the natural numbers group excluding $0$.
>
> Prove that $B_n∩B_m=B_{c(n,m)}$  where $c(n,m)$ is the least common multiple of $n,m$.

Comment: What have you done to solve this, and where do you get stuck?

Comment: Ideally you will prove it. We have two sets, $B_n\cap B_m$ and $B_{c(n,m)}$. We want to prove these two sets are the same. There are two things that need to be done: (i) show that if $x$ is an element of the left-hand side, then $x$ is an element of the right-hand side and (ii) if $x$ is an element of the RHS, it is an element of the LHS.

Comment: Well I understand it clearly intuitively , but I just couldn't manage to write a formal proof for that.

Comment: Yeah I get that perfectly, I just couldn't write a formal proof that shows that. i'm really discouraged!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use the following notation in order not to write too much

$n\mid m$ if and only if there exists $k$ in $\Bbb Z$ such that $m=kn.$, for $m,n$ in $\Bbb Z$ we define

$$\mathrm{lcd}(m,n)=\min\{u\in \Bbb N\colon m\mid u\mbox{ and } n\mid u\}.$$

in this notation, we have that $x\in B\;n$ if and only if $n\mid x$. You can use the following well know property of LCM to prove that equality:

Let $u$ in $\Bbb N$. Then $\mathrm{lcd}(m,n)\mid u$ holds if and only if $n\mid u$ and $m\mid u$.

For see that $B\;c(n,m)= B\;n\cap B\;m$. If $x\in B\;c(n,m)$ then $c(n,m)|x$ and by the property, $n\mid x$ and $m\mid x$, so $x \in B\;n\cap B\;m$. If $x\in B\;n\cap B\;m$, if $n\mid x$ and $m\mid x$ then $\mathrm{lcd}(n,m)\mid x$ and $x\in B\;\mathrm{lcd}(n,m)$.

Comment: well writen and explained, thank you very very much!

Answer (score 1):

Let us try to prove that $B_n\cap B_m\subseteq B_{\text{lcm}(m,n)}$

To do so, suppose that $x\in B_n\cap B_m$.  That is to say, $x$ is a multiple of $n$ and a multiple of $m$.  As every multiple of both $m$ and $n$ is also a multiple of $\text{lcm}(m,n)$ (*should provide more details or cite a theorem here*) it follows that $x\in B_{m,n}$

Now, let us look at the reverse direction.  That is, we want to show $B_{\text{lcm}(m,n)}\subseteq B_n\cap B_m$

Let $x\in B_{\text{lcm(m,n)}}$, that is, $x$ is a multiple of the least common multiple of $m$ and $n$.  But as the least common multiple of $m$ and $n$ is itself a *multiple* of $m$ and is also a multiple of $n$, it follows that $x$ is a multiple of $m$ and $x$ is a multiple of $n$.  Thus, $x\in B_n\cap B_m$

As we showed any element taken from the left side must also be an element of the right and any element taken from the right side must also be an element of the left, we have shown that the two sets are in fact the same.

---

Additional details:  If $x$ is a multiple of $y$ and $y$ is a multiple of $z$ then $x$ is a multiple of $z$

Proof:  $x=ky$ for some integer $k$ and $y=jz$ for some integer $j$.  It follows then that $x=kjz=(kj)z$

---

If $x$ is a multiple of $m$ and $x$ is a multiple of $n$ then $x$ is a multiple of $\text{lcm(m,n)}$

Proof: Let $m=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_N^{\alpha_N}$ and $n=p_1^{\beta_1}p_2^{\beta_2}\dots p_N^{\beta_N}$ and $x=p_1^{\gamma_1}p_2^{\gamma_2}\dots p_N^{\gamma_N}$ be representations of $m,n,x$ as products of powers of primes as guaranteed to exist via the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

As $x$ is a multiple of $m$, we have $x=mk$ for some $k=p_1^{\kappa_1}p_2^{\kappa_2}\dots p_N^{\kappa_N}$.  Then $x=mk=p_1^{\alpha_1+\kappa_1}p_2^{\alpha_2+\kappa_2}\dots p_N^{\alpha_N+\kappa_N}$.  Then $\gamma_i=\alpha_i+\kappa_i\geq \alpha_i$ for all $i$.  Furthermore as $x$ is a multiple of $n$ we have $\gamma_i\geq \beta_i$ for all $i$.  Therefore $\gamma_i\geq \max(\alpha_i,\beta_i)$ for all $i$.

As $\text{lcm(m,n)}=p_1^{\max(\alpha_1,\beta_1)}p_2^{\max(\alpha_2,\beta_2)}\dots p_N^{\max(\alpha_N,\beta_N)}$ it follows that $x=\text{lcm}(m,n)\cdot (p_1^{\gamma_1-\max(\alpha_1,\beta_1)}p_2^{\gamma_2-\max(\alpha_2,\beta_2)}\dots)$, the number on the right being an integer.  Thus, $x$ is a multiple of $\text{lcm}(m,n)$

Comment: Thank you, but how do I go about showing that every x is a multiple of n and m is a multiple of lcm(m,n) .that's where I was originally stuck